# the condition works out in a strange way in Angular

Tags: angular

```
<ng-template *ngIf="reports.length > 0; else emptyReports">
  {{ reports.length }}
</ng-template>

<ng-template #emptyReports">
  empty
</ng-template>
```

So, the condition works out in a strange way.
When loading, it shows `empty` (literally for 0.1 seconds), then the blank page. What should be added/changed?

**component.ts**

```
reports = []

ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get<any>(`supplier/reports.json`)
  .subscribe(data => this.reports = data.reports);
}
```

Comment: They're both `ng-template`s. They won't be rendered unless you render them. You can convert first `ng-template` to `ng-container`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Ouch. You are right! (I've been studying Angular for about a month, I completely forgot about it. Thank you!)

Comment: Glad you solved it. Happy coding!